# In a data structure designed for efficiency, if you often use a temporary int or float, is it best to make it a field?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, types

A little more background, I have a data structure that when removing or adding or simply retrieving I temporarily use a float as temporary storage in the methods. Instead of asking for a new spot in memory to put this float, and have the garbage collector have to collect it a few lines later, would it be better to reserve the space as a field, then we are simply changing the value, and not having to constantly waste time with garbage collection and reallocating memory space?

In the situation I am doing this on is Android, and that garbage collector is a pain and every object I can save significantly helps.

Comment: Primitives like `float`s and `int`s are not objects, and they are put on the stack, they don't get garbage-collected (until and unless you need to box them into a `Float` or `Integer` for use where you need an object).  If you can keep a primitive local, do it, especially if you're concerned about memory over computation as you seem to be.

Comment: For performance, its best to use local variables rather than fields whenever practical.

Answer (score 4):

No, just use a local variable for this purpose.  Traditionally a local variable is allocated a place in the procedure stack frame or possibly just in a machine register.  In either case, the interaction with a garbage collector is a nonissue:  the variable storage goes away when the stack frame is popped & the procedure returns.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use instance variables for temporary locations for methods.

- Instance variables occupy space on the object; i.e. they make it bigger.  The space is used as long as the object exists.  There are likely to be more instances than there are calls to a method, so even if there was a sound reason to do this, putting temporaries into instance variables would most likely use more space for longer than the alternative.
- Instance variables are shared by all threads that use a particular instance, and also by reentrant (recursive) calls on an object in the same thread.  If you use them to hold temporaries, you risk one method call / thread interfering with another.

Use local variables instead.  That's what they are intended for.